# Como ocultar o endereço de email

Tags: c#, envio-de-email

Estou fazendo um algoritmo que faz envio de emails, estou conseguindo enviar os emails normalmente, porém gostaria de poder ocultar o endereço de email de quem esta enviando para o destinatário.

obs: quando falo em ocultar o endereço de email, me refiro ao Header do email, no qual aparece o nome do remetente e o endereço de email entre '<>'. Gostaria de ocultar o endereço quem vem dentro dos sinais de menor e maior.

Codigo C# :

```
    public HttpResponseMessage SendMail()
    {
        try
        {
            MailMessage _mailMessage = new MailMessage();

            _mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("emailRemetente", "nomeRemetente");

            _mailMessage.CC.Add(emailDestinatario);
            _mailMessage.Subject = "Título do email";
            _mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
            _mailMessage.Body = "Corpo do email HTML";


            SmtpClient _smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtpclient", Convert.ToInt32(porta));

            _smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            _smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("emailRemetente", "senhaRemetente");

            _smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;

            _smtpClient.Send(_mailMessage);

            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, true);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Dei uma lida neste link : https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.mailmessage.bcc?view=netframework-4.8 mas não entendi muito bem.

Comment: Tentou simplesmente passar um `string.Empty` ou repetir o endereço do e-mail no display name? O você está se referindo de fato ao endereço de envio para onde o receptor responderia? Última pergunta, por quê?

Comment: @Leandro Angelo Não porque eu quero que apareça um nome que eu irei determinar.

Comment: @Leandro Angelo resposta para a segunda pergunta: Sim, estou me referindo ao endereço de email onde o receptor responderia.

Comment: @Leandro Angelo resposta para a última pergunta: Porque o meu chefe pediu :)

Comment: Pergunta pra ele, se ele já recebeu algum e-mail sem remetente.

Comment: Esse link que você colocou como exemplo não cobre o que você quer, ele serve para quando por exemplo se envia e-mail a duas pessoas e elas não vejam que era para ambas, como o Leandro Angelo disse, não é possível enviar um e-mail sem identificação

Comment: @Lucas Miranda OK, obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ao invés de usar o método CC, use o Bcc, ele é o campo CCO (Com Cópia Oculta) em inglês.

Na prática:

**ao invés de usar** o _mailMessage.**CC**.Add(emailDestinatario)

**use** o _mailMessage.**Bcc**.Add(emailDestinatario).